# How to target the last active slide in slick js using CSS

Tags: css, sass, css-selectors, slick.js

I am using Slick JS plugin. By default there is a class "slick-slide" that is added on all the slides. I notice that the slides that are in currently visible have a another class added called "slick-active".

Lets say I want to display 3 slides (slidesToShow: 3). So at all times all the slides in view will have 2 classes namely "slick-slide" and "slick-active".

[image: A quick inspect element of slick slides]

I am trying to target the last slide which has the class "slick-active" using CSS. I tried all possible combinations of selectors, but no luck so far.

First I am giving a right margin to all the elements with "slick-active" class. Then I would like to target just using css the last element with "slick active" class, and give margin right of 0.

```
.slick-active {
    margin-right: 15px;
    background: blueviolet;
}

.slick-slide.slick-active:last-of-type {
    margin-right: 0;
    background: orangered;
}
```

I even tried using **nth-last-of-type(1)** and **nth-last-child()** selectors. Can someone please suggest me the correct CSS selector to target the last slide with a class of slick-active. I dont want to target the slides using javascript or jquery. Just a pure CSS solution will be appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

```
.slick-slide.slick-active:last-child {
   //property
}
```

worked for me

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `+` selector:

```
.slick-active + .slick-active + .slick-active {
  //your property
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to provide a separate id to the slide if it is not being created dynamically. And then apply your required CSS.

Answer (score 0):

We have to target last child specifically.

```css
.slick-active:nth-child(3) {
  color: red;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I don't just want to target the 3rd slide. I would like to target the last slide always.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
.slick-active:nth-child(3n){}
```

See this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/shuaibkhan1911/3pwt1ask/3/)